# Font color change of data field have hyperlink

Tags: crystal-reports

Currently,

In crystal report, there are 5 field in data section.
Following hyperlink is set to all 5 fields.
Hyperlink="URL/Page.aspx?query1="+totext({@param1})+"&query2="+totext({@param2}2)

3.By default font color of the data field is black.

4.In above scenario, when mouse is move to individual field then hand cursor is displayed on that field.

As per requirement , we want to do the followings

Single hyperlink should be considered for all 5 fields.
When mouse is move over to any field then font color of the whole record (i.e. all 5 fields) should be changed to blue.
We are currently using SAP crystal report runtime engine for .NET Framework(64-bit)(Version-13.0.182192) with Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 0):

The single hyperlink can be achieved by placing the fields inside a single text object (or above/below a blank text object).
The hover behavior is not exposed in Crystal (and repainting requires reload). So the 2nd half of your requirement is not compatible with Crystal.